# Table with more columns on some rows

Tags: tables

[image]

How do you create a table just like above, with different number of visible columns depending on the rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you show an intended application? Usually such tables are better realized in different formats.

Answer (score 4):

See: [enter link description here](http://www.fiz-ix.com/2012/01/making-latex-figures-with-custom-cell-borders/)

```
\documentclass{article}
% Kommentieren Sie die folgende Zeile aus um das Einbinden von Grafiken zu ermöglichen (.png, .jpg)
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
% Kommentieren Sie die folgende Zeile ein um KEINE Umlaute zu ermöglichen
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
% Das Dokument beginnt hier
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{numbers} \\
\cline{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{sideways} letters~ \end{sideways}} & A & A1 & A2 & A3 \\
\cline{2-5}
& B & B1 & B2 & B3 \\
\cline{2-5}
& C & C1 & C2 & C3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
%\caption{Table caption.}
%\label{Table2}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]